I can't seem to properly solve for $y$ with a hyperbolic equation to input in graphing calculator
Maybe I'm just tired but for the life of me I can't seem to get the equation in the form shown in the attached pic.
These are the steps I used to get the wrong answer.

Get $\frac{y^2}{49}$ to the right side.

Get $1$ to the left side.

Multiply both sides by $49$ to eliminate the denominator for $\frac{y^2}{49}$.

Take the square root of both sides to isolate $y$.


I know that this is a simple algebraic equation and despite my studying algebra, trigonometry, and the rest of precalculus, I am whiffing on this simple algebra.
I know I'm making a simple initial mistake.
Any tips on where I am in error would be greatly appreciated.


if there is some $A \geq 0$   and $y^2 = A$   then $y = \pm \sqrt A $

Your steps so far look fine to me. It's hard to say what went wrong with your calculations without actually seeing your final result.

What is the value of $y$ for $x=10$? You do have the two solutions $7\sqrt3$ and $-7\sqrt3$. But for definition of function, for all $x$ you must have  only one $f(x)$. You need to agree with two functions.
